# How can I instruct draftwatermark package to exclude the first few pages

Tags: watermark, page, draftwatermark

The package [`draftwatermark`](https://ctan.org/pkg/draftwatermark) has been quite useful. However, I want to suppress the watermark only on the first 3 pages of my thesis. How can I achieve this?

Here's a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you add code to the fourth page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change a boolean to suppress the printing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter\@sc@wm@stampfalse\makeatother
\blindtext[1]

\newpage 
\makeatletter\@sc@wm@stamptrue\makeatother
\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work. Set the lightness to `1` for the pages on which you do not want to have a watermark, and set it to a different value for the other pages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\SetWatermarkLightness{1}
\lipsum[1-10]
\clearpage
\SetWatermarkLightness{0.5}
\lipsum[10-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The same result is obtained with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\SetWatermarkLightness{\ifnum\thepage<3
1
\else
0.5
\fi}
\lipsum[1-10]
\clearpage
\lipsum[10-20]

\end{document}
```

with which you can switch on the watermark from p. 3 onward.